# xcode symbol navigator for Swift Playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

While I code along on [Swift Talk episode 8](https://talk.objc.io/)

I was stuck for a while on working on Resource structure.

```
enum HttpMethod<Body> {
    case get
    case post(Body)
}

struct Resource<A> {
    let url: URL
    let method: HttpMethod<Data>
    let parse: (Data) -> A?
}

extension Resource {
    init(url: URL, method: HttpMethod<Any> = . get, parseJSON: @escaping (Any) -> A?) {
        self.url = url
        self.method = method.map { json in
            // TODO: try! is not safe here anymore
            return try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [])
        }
        self.parse = { data in
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            return json.flatMap(parseJSON)
        }
    }
}
```

Called from:

```
func pushNotification(token: String) -> Resource<Bool> {
    let url = URL(string: "")!
    let dictionary = ["token": token]
    return Resource(url: url, method: .post(dictionary), parse: { _ in
        return true
    })    //** my mistake was on this line (see below) 
}
```

Then I got the following error message:

> Networking.playground/Pages/Step 10.xcplaygroundpage:118:40: Member 'post' in 'HttpMethod<Data>' produces result of type 'HttpMethod<Body>', but context expects 'HttpMethod<Data>'

Took me a while to realized that I have called the memberwise initializer for the Resource structure:  init(url:method:parse:) while I should call the custom initializer:  init(url:method:parseJSON:)
(note: the memberwise initializer still exist since we add the custom initializer in extension)

In retrospection, I thought, have I used the Symbol Navigator, I might have found my mistake sooner.  But after spending some time on Xcode, I can't figure out how to view symbol navigator for Swift Playground. It's always empty.

I checked on my other Xcode swift project, symbol navigator works properly.

Anybody know how could we get the symbol navigator to work properly in Xcode Swift Playground?